# Global and local symmetry for Isospin/Strangeness etc

Tags: symmetry, gauge-theory, isospin-symmetry

Why some symmetries $ \big[SU(3),SU(2)$ and $U(1)\big]$ of the Standard Model are local, and some others remain global, like Isospin and Strangeness.
Is there a fundumental reason for that?
Doesn't it cause problem to relativity?